# Is "this last year" proper English?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, determiners

> I've admired @BernieSanders' courage for 20 years and loved getting to know him this last year on the trail.    —[Pete Buttigieg](https://mobile.twitter.com/petebuttigieg/status/1247917718449381377?lang=en)

It seems to mean "in the past twelve months" according to my research.

Comment: Need context.  Eg, "What were you doing this last year?", while not exactly clear, would be considered idiomatic speech.

Comment: Of course it's proper English. It was spoken and understood by native speakers.

Comment: Yeah, in that context it's easily understood.

Answer (score 2):

> Is “this last year” proper English?

Yes, it means "in the 12 months prior to today"

This contrasts with "last year" which [currently, and in most contexts,] refers to the whole of 2019.

Have a look at the examples given in [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%20last%20year&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20last%20year%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthis%20last%20year%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

I came across a very similar phase while reading Pride and Prejudice.

> “Mr. Bennet, how can you abuse you own children in such a way? You take delight in vexing me. You have no compassion for my poor nerves.”
>
> “You mistake me, my dear. I have a high respect  for your nerves. They are my old friends. I have heard you mention them with consideration **these last twenty years** at least.”

Comment: Where does that say yes, no or maybe to the Question?

Comment: I think this is answering "Yes" to the question, and providing supporting evidence from Jane Austen. But it's certainly an oblique answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard *this last year* before, and the phrase will be understood as "in the past twelve months".

That said, for some reason I can't articulate, *this last year* has always sounded inferior to these other options:

> a. this past year
>
> b. in the past/last year

Answer (score -3):

No, I do not think that "this last year" is proper English, but Buttigieg may have made a small mistake and typed "last" instead of "past."

Comment: What you've written here would have been better suited to being a comment or a question of its own. You  will be able to leave comments on other's posts as soon as you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).